# Add a check box and text to an li dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a check box and text to an li dynamically

Here is my code

```
var statusList = document.createElement('ul');
for (var item in object) {
    var option = document.createElement('li');
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.name = "name";
    checkbox.value = "value";
    //these are the things I have tried. I can get the title or the checkbox 
      but not both
    //option.appendChild(checkbox); this adds the checkbox but not the text
    //option.appendChild(object[item]); this throws an error
    //option.text = checkbox + object[item]; this populates an empty li
    //option.innerHTML = checkbox + object[item]; this populates the 
    //checkbox but not as an element. in other words it will say 
    //[object HTMLInputElement] + text
    //option.text = object[item]; this populates the text but not checkbox
    option.value = item;
    statusList.appendChild(option);
}
```

please DO NOT give jquery answers. only javascript

Comment: `option.appendChild(checkbox);option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("TEXT"));`

Comment: @Passerby if you put your response as the answer, I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending from comment:

[Text node is also a node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType), so you can append it like normal Element:

```
option.appendChild(checkbox);
option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("TEXT")‌​);
```

[MDN: `document.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode)
[MDN: `Element.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)